# Как послать JSON в теле HTTP-ответа?

Tags: c#, openlayers, json, http, ajax

Отдается JSON так:

```
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add(new Uri("http://localhost:8181"));
listener.Start();
while (isListening) {
  HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
  HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
  HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
  //...
  MemoryStream ms = (GeoJsonDeserialize.SerializeGeoJson(ObjToJson) as MemoryStream);
  byte[] buffer = ms.ToArray();
  response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
  response.KeepAlive = false;
  response.ContentType = "application/json";
  response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
  response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
  response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "private, max-age=0");
  Stream output = response.OutputStream;
  output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
  ms = new MemoryStream();
  ms.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
  buffer = ms.ToArray();
  output.Close();
}
```

В другой проге на C# я запрашиваю так:

```
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8181");
WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
String str = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

и вижу переданный текст (*JSON*).
Но вот беда - ни *Ajax* не видит тело ответа (выдает ошибку), ни *OpenLayers* который по *GeoJSON* должен показать точки на карте.

OpenLayers запрашивает данные (за основу взят пример ***OpenLayersRotationExample***):

```
vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector( "Simple Geometry", {
  protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
    url: "http://localhost:8181",   format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
  }),
  strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()]
});
map.addLayers([vectors]);
```

Объект в JSON ([GeoJSON](http://gis-lab.info/docs/geojson_ru.html)) выглядит так:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-108.04,44.68]},"properties":{"course":184.7}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-111.04,45.68]},"properties":{"course":44.1}}]}
```

Специально пробовал текст передаваемого JSON загрузить в OL непосредственно в JavaScript:

```
var featurecollection = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-111.04,45.68]},"properties":{"course":42.9}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-111.04,45.68]},"properties":{"course":157.5}}]};
var geojson_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();
var vector_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Simple 1", {
styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
  "default": {
     externalGraphic: "OpenLayersRotationExample_files/marker-gold.png",
         //graphicWidth: 17,
         graphicHeight: 20,
         graphicYOffset: -19,
         rotation: "${course}",
     },
     "select": {
        cursor: "crosshair",
        externalGraphic: "OpenLayersRotationExample_files/marker.png"
     }
  })
}); 
map.addLayer(vector_layer);
vector_layer.addFeatures(geojson_format.read(featurecollection));
```

И все работает - точки отображаются.
Вывод - я неправильно отдаю JSON.
Подскажите как в ответ на запрос отдать JSON что бы JavaScript его смог принять?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, в ответе от сервера вам приходит текст. Соответственно, его надо преобразовать в объект. Можете eval'ом, а можете подключить библиотеку для работы с json'ом.

Comment: В том то и беда что JS ничего не принимает вообще - потому и спрашиваю, что не понимаю в чем дело (ведь все дело запускается локально - HTML страница и приложение на C#).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поскольку провайдер точек и страница отображающая карту находится в разных доменах, действует [Same Orign Policy](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0).

В OpenLayers есть `OpenLayers.Protocol.Script` который использует [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) для получения данных. По умолчанию callback называется `OpenLayers.Protocol.Script.registry.c1`. Вам необходимо переделать провайдер соответствующим образом, чтобы он оборачивал результирующий JSON в эту функцию.

Comment: Спасибо, сделал так:  

    vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(Simple Geometry", {
      protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.Script({
       url: "http://localhost:8181/",
       callbackKey: "format_options",
       callbackPrefix: "callback:",
       filterToParams: function(filter, params) {
         if (filter.type === OpenLayers.Filter.Spatial.BBOX) {
           params.bbox = filter.value.toArray();
           if (filter.projection) { params.bbox.push(filter.projection.getCode()); }
         }
         return params;
       }
     })
    });

Осталось разобраться в том что написал...

Comment: Вот этого вам хватит:

    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.Script({
        url: "http://localhost:8181/",
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
    })

Запрос к источнику будет выглядеть так:
    http://localhost:8181/?callback=OpenLayers.Protocol.Script.registry.c1

А в ответе должна быть функция переданная в параметре `callback`:

    OpenLayers.Protocol.Script.registry.c1({
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        ......
    });

Comment: А почему может вываливаться ошибка

    Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'c1'

из-за которой не срабатывает стратегия обновления, другими словами точки на карте не обновляют своего положения, выводясь один раз?

Comment: Ну, например из за того что нет такой функции у объекта. При использовании OpenLayers.Strategy.Refresh callback при каждом запросе разный, поэтому учтите это при написании вашего JSONP-провайдера.