# Правила и фильтры OpenLayers (отбор по свойствам объектов)

Tags: c#, json, javascript, openlayers, geojson

Есть GeoJSON вида:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-108.04,44.68]},"properties":{"course":184.7,"vid":1}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-111.04,45.68]},"properties":{"course":44.1,"vid":2}}]}
```

Являющийся источником слоя **vectors** (см. ["Как послать JSON в теле HTTP-ответа?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/146148/c-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-json-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5-http-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0)).
Нужен фильтр показывающий только точки с **vid** входящим массив, вида:

```
var pointShow = [1,3];
```

Вроде бы для этого нужно использовать правила (*Rule*), но я с OpenLayers не особо знаком, да и в интернете найти что-то по теме кроме описания [FeatureId](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Filter/FeatureId-js.html) на сайте "*OpenLayers*" не получилось.

Пробовал сделать так:

```
var myStyle = new OpenLayers.Style();
var defRule = new OpenLayers.Rule({
    filter: new OpenLayers.Filter.FeatureId({fids: ["2242"]}),
    symbolizer: {
        externalGraphic: "OpenLayersRotationExample_files/marker-red.png",
        graphicWidth: 21,
        graphicHeight: 25,
        graphicXOffset: -10,
        graphicYOffset: -12
    }
});
myStyle.addRules([defRule]);

...

vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
   "Simple Geometry",
   {
      protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.Script({
        url: "http://localhost:8181/view",
        callbackKey: "format_options",
        callbackPrefix: "callback:",
        filterToParams: function(filter, params) {
          if (filter.type === OpenLayers.Filter.Spatial.BBOX) {
            params.bbox = filter.value.toArray();
            if (filter.projection) {
              params.bbox.push(filter.projection.getCode());
            }
          }
          return params;
        }
      }),
      strategies: [
        new OpenLayers.Strategy.Refresh({force: true, interval:10000}),
        new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX({resFactor:2})
      ],
      styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
        "default": myStyle
      })
   }
);
```

Но в итоге я ничего не вижу.

В связи с этим вопрос - как правильно писать правила и фильтры **OpenLayers**?
Буду признателен за полезные ссылки на примеры и примеры использования разных фиьтров, в частности **FeatureId** (желательно более понятных чем тут "[Filtering a WFS Layer](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.openlayers.user/12372)").

***PS***: Пока решил так:

```
var myStyle = new OpenLayers.Style();
var defRule = new OpenLayers.Rule({
  symbolizer: {
    externalGraphic: "OpenLayersRotationExample_files/marker.png",
    graphicWidth: 14,
    graphicHeight: 17,
    graphicXOffset: -7,
    graphicYOffset: -8,
    graphicOpacity: 0.9,
    rotation: "${course}",
    display: "none"
  }
});
myStyle.addRules([defRule]);
for (keyVar in arr) {
  myStyle.addRules([
    new OpenLayers.Rule({
      filters: [new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
        property: "vid",
        value: arr[keyVar]
      }),
      symbolizer: {
        externalGraphic: "OpenLayersRotationExample_files/marker-red.png",
        display: ""
      }
    })
  ])
}

//arr - список id объектов которые нужно показать
//vid, course - поля свойств объектов (properties)
```

Возможно не очень красиво и медленно, но работает. Кто знает как разобраться с *FeatureId*, прошу подскажите - все таки, я думаю, он быстрее отработает чем куча фильтров.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас JSON не полный. У каждой feature должен быть некоторый `"id"`, по которому фильтровать фильтром FeatureId.

Comment: У меня его роль играет **vid**. Можете сказать как именно должно называться свойство что бы **FeatureId** его воспринял именно как *ID*

Comment: должно называться `"id"` и быть в блоке вместе с `"type":"Feature"`. А `"vid"` находится в `"properties"` - это как-бы дополнительные свойства.


    {
      "type":"Feature",
      "id": 1,
      "geometry":{
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[-108.04,44.68]
      },
      "properties":{
        "course":184.7,
        "vid":1
      }
    }